# Could not instantiate SchemaTypeSystemImpl (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException): is the version of xbean.jar correct?

Tags: java, apache-poi, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am writing an application to export data to an Excel sheet.

I downloaded the Apache POI libraries and I included the following libraries to my project: - poi-4.0.1.jar

While converting jar to native image using graalvm, I'm getting the following runtime error.
The jar is getting executing using the command prompt.

Comment: Did you include all of the Apache POI dependencies too?

Comment: Yes, it is working in eclipse and report is getting generated without any error